# Is it possible to obtain Request Body via Application_BeginRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Just as stated by the title; I was researching this but didn't find any specifics on retrieving the full Request Body for a POST. Any ideas if this is possible, I need it to populate a server variable for IIS.

I have the following code:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
            BindingFlags temp = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

            MethodInfo addStatic = null;
            MethodInfo makeReadOnly = null;
            MethodInfo makeReadWrite = null;

            Type type = application.Request.ServerVariables.GetType();
            MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods(temp);

            foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
            {
                switch (method.Name)
                {
                    case "MakeReadWrite": 
                        makeReadWrite = method;
                        break;
                    case "MakeReadOnly": 
                        makeReadOnly = method;
                        break;
                    case "AddStatic": 
                        addStatic = method;
                        break;
                }
            }

            makeReadWrite.Invoke(application.Request.ServerVariables, null);

            //GOAL IS TO RETRIEVE REQUEST BODY TO POPULATE SERVER VARIABLE, THEN DISPLAY VIA IIS.
            //MY CURRENT USE OF application.Request.Form DOESN'T WORK OF COURSE.
            string[] values = { "RequestFormParams", application.Request.Form.ToString() };

            addStatic.Invoke(application.Request.ServerVariables, values);
            makeReadOnly.Invoke(application.Request.ServerVariables, null);
        }
```

Comment: I believe that answer is no. Since request body stream is not seekable code needs to cooperate with framework that handles the request to avoid reading body twice.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for clearing this up a bit, you said "needs to cooperate with framework that handles the request", In my case that would be .NET, no? If so, Do you have anything I can look at to get an idea on how to implement this?

Comment: "framework" in more narrow sense - WebAPI, ASP.Net MVC, ASP.Net WebForms, APS.Net ASMX... For web services something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824639.aspx, for MVC possibly global action filter (to run after stream is read)...